# How to mapping Co-Authors Plus author to post while migrate db

Tags: wordpress

I imported all wp_users & wp_usermeta from one wp_db (old site) to another wp_db (new site) successfully with sql query & also mapped posts with their respective **post_author** but old site installed **Co-Authors Plus** plugin so I also installed **Co-Authors Plus** plugin at new site but the posts does not shows correct authors

**Old Site**

[image]

**New Site**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but to solve this what I did was import all the articles using a single author and then in Excel create a line of php code that would specifically add the co-authors for the article. So:

```
$post_id = 8077;$authors = array( 'Brock');$coauthors_plus->add_coauthors( 8077, $authors );
```

Replace all the actual data with cell references for ease. Not the prettiest or most fun, but it works and seems to be the best solution using what I've found online. Hopefully you already found an answer, but others may find this helpful.